# How to replace integers in multidimensional arrays with strings

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I am generating a table in PDF format. There is a multidimensional array of integers and strings, and I have inputs. If the array's values are equal to the inputs, I replace the values with `'O'`, otherwise with `'X'`. I would like to replace the other values with `'x'`. I want to print:

```
[a][b][c][d]

[ ][O][X][X]

[ ][X][X][X]
```

Anybody help? My code is:

```
n = 0
Array = [["a","b","c", "d"]] +
[[" "]+[n,n+1,n+2].map{ |n| n + 1 }] + 
[[" "]+[n+3,n+4,n+5].map { |n| n + 1 }]

Array.collect! do |i| 
    if i.include?(1) #assume, input is 1
        i[i.index(1)] = 'X'; i
    else
        i
    end
end
```

Results:

```
[a][b][c][d]

[ ][X][2][3]

[ ][4][5][6]
```

Comment: is your array always going to be 2-dimensional?

Comment: When do you replace with `'X'`, and when with `'x'`? It is not clear at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you can loop through array multidimensional, from your sample is array two dimension(x,y)
I replaced array name with arr1

```
n = 0
arr1 = [["a","b","c", "d"]] +
[[" "]+[n,n+1,n+2].map{ |n| n + 1 }] + 
[[" "]+[n+3,n+4,n+5].map { |n| n + 1 }]

# this is how you replace
arr1.each_with_index do |x, xi|
  x.each_with_index do |y, yi|
    if y.is_a? Integer
      x[yi] = 'X'
    end
  end
end

# this is how you check the result
arr1.each_with_index do |x, xi|
  x.each_with_index do |y, yi|
    puts "element [#{xi}, #{yi}] is #{y}"
  end
end
```

and this is the output

```
element [0, 0] is a
element [0, 1] is b
element [0, 2] is c
element [0, 3] is d
element [1, 0] is
element [1, 1] is X
element [1, 2] is X
element [1, 3] is X
element [2, 0] is
element [2, 1] is X
element [2, 2] is X
element [2, 3] is X
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all integers to 'X' and return the required array.

```
n = 0
Array = [["a","b","c", "d"]] +
[[" "]+[n,n+1,n+2].map{ |n| n + 1 }] + 
[[" "]+[n+3,n+4,n+5].map { |n| n + 1 }]


Array.map { |a| a.map! { |b| (b.is_a? Integer) ? 'X' : b } }
```